# CSS bootstrap button modification. Color only changes half when hover

Tags: css

I don't know what's wrong with my CSS. I'm trying to create a new class called "btn-success2" with new colors by modifying default bootstrap colors. I'm trying to set my hover color to white but it only changes half of it. The top part is still the same green color.

My code as below:

```
.btn-success2:hover,
.btn-success2:focus,
.btn-success2:active,
.btn-success2.active,
.btn-success2.disabled,
.btn-success2[disabled] {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #fff;
  *background-color: #fff;
}

.btn-success2:active,
.btn-success2.active {
  background-color: #6cc334 \9;
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ms4uk83e/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had:         background-position: 0 -15px;

Change the -15px to 30.

```
.btn:hover, .btn:focus {
    background-position: 0 -30px;
}
```

Comment: thanks, this works... can you also tell me how to turn off the animation....? when hover, the color changes from bottom to top slowly... I want it to change the whole button at one shot...

Comment: You have this css   

-webkit-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
  -moz-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
  -o-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
  transition: background-position 0.1s linear;

get rid of it :p  thats doing the transition


add this instead: .btn:hover,
.btn:focus {
  color: #333333 !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #fff;
}

Answer (score 2):

It's because of background-position: 0 -15px; to .btn:hover,
.btn:focus class. Try this,

```
.btn:hover,
.btn:focus {
  color: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-position: 0 -30px;
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
  -moz-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
  -o-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
  transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `.btn:hover` : `{background-position: 0 -15px;}` , 
change `-15` to `-30` can work. But may not your real intention.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem but I knew the following code had worked previously and some other change had caused this issue:

```
.btn:hover,
.btn:focus {
  background-position: 0 -15px;
}
```

So I was sceptical of the other answers' suggestion of changing the `background-position` from `-15px` to `-30px`, plus I could see from the Bootstrap code that the stock buttons also had `-15px` for hover/focus.

It turned out I had a duplicate CSS declaration for my particular btn type (`.btn-primary` in my case). **Removing the duplicate CSS fixed the issue for me**.